# Regular Expression - HTML

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I am kind of new to regular expressions, but the one i made myself doesn't work. It is supposed to give me data from a websites html.

I basically want to get this out of html, and all of the multiple ones. I have the page url as a string btw.

```
<a href="http://store.steampowered.com/search/?category2=2" class="name">Co-Op</a>
```

And what i've done for my regexp is:

```
<a\bhref="http://store.steampowered.com/search/?category2=2"\bclass="name"*>(.*?)</a>\g
```

Comment: Using regex to parse HTML is generally a bad idea.  You'll be much better off using an HTML parsing library or tool

Answer (score 3):

You should never parse HTML/XML or any other language that allows cascading using regular expressions.

A nice thing with HTML however, is that it can be converted to XML and XML has a nice toolkit for parsing:

```
echo '<a href="http://store.steampowered.com/search/?category2=2" class="name">Co-Op</a>' | tidy -asxhtml -numeric 2> /dev/null | xmllint --html --xpath 'normalize-space(//a[@class="name" and @href="http://store.steampowered.com/search/?category2=2"])' - 2>/dev/null
```

With query:

```
normalize-space(//a[@class="name" and @href="http://store.steampowered.com/search/?category2=2"])
```

`//` means any tag (regardless of it's *depth*), `a` means the `a` tag, and we furthermore specify the constraints that `class=name` and `href=(the link)`. And then we returned the `normalize-space` content between the such tag `<a>` and `</a>`.

In Python you can use:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = urllib2.urlopen("http://store.steampowered.com/app/24860/").read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
print soup.find_all('a',attrs={'class':'name','href':'http://store.steampowered.com/search/?category2=2'})
```

---

Comment on your regex:

the problem is that it contains tokens like `?` that are interpreted as regex-directives rather than characters. You need to escape them. It should probably read:

```
<a\s+href="http://store\.steampowered\.com/search/\?category2=2"\s+class="name"\S*>(.*?)</a>\g
```

I also replaced `\b` with `\s`, `\s` means space characters like space, tab, new line. Although the regex is quite fragile: if one ever decides to swap `href` and `class`, the program has a problem. For most of these problems, there are indeed solutions, but you better use an XML analysis tool.

Comment: The first problem in the regex seems to me that `a\bhref` never matches anything, and certainly not `a href`. It asks for a word boundary between the letters `ah`, which cannot exist without additional characters. Actually, scratch that, that’s the second problem. I agree on the first problem: regex for parsing is a bad idea.

Comment: @JonasRH: That simple linux `bash`, but there exist XML analyzers for Python as well.

Comment: Well i use something called BeautifulSoup, an html parser, but it still doesn't seem to find anything... That is why i tried to use regexp instead.